# Versioning with ResourceUrlEncodingFilter - filter called but not encodeURL

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

Hi I'm working on Versioning with ResourceUrlEncodingFilter, from debug i can confirm ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal is called but not ResourceUrlEncodingResponseWrapper.encodeURL, which is a bit strange.

Here's my configuration:

MvcConfig(extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter)

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {     
    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/assets/")
            .setCachePeriod(31536000)
            .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
}

@Bean
public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
    return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
}

//...and other freemarket config
```

web.xml

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/assets/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
<!-- and other config -->
```

ftl example:

```html
<link href="<@spring.url '/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Result:
when asset link is called, ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal is called (from debug), but ResourceUrlEncodingResponseWrapper.encodeURL is not.
From Chrome, the css is not versioned.

Is my configuration correct? Did I miss something?

The server i'm using is Wildfly 9.0.2, Spring/MVC 4.2, Spring Security 4.0.3

ref:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources
http://www.mscharhag.com/spring/resource-versioning-with-spring-mvc

Comment: Did some digging, the spring.ftl use RequestContext.getContextUrl(String)
- is there a way to override it?
- also trying to use ControllerAdvise with ResourceUrlProvider, the url is ok but chrome return 404, seems like the resolver cannot resolve the encoded url, any clue?

Comment: sorry figured i shouldn't override it, as it mess up with other relative url